# Clean Install win 7 after win 10 has been installed?

Tags: windows

I bought a new pc (all in one) with win 8.1 and I upgraded to win 10. My old pc was win 7 ultimate and i like to install win 7 in my new pc to be able to run all the old progs. Can I do this?

Comment: Any program that ran on Windows 7 should have no problem running on Windows 10 or Windows 8.1.  There should nothing that prevents you from running Windows 7 on this new PC, except if there not compatible device drivers, but you indicate nothing about the PC itself.  It is easy enough to have a system drive so you can boot to Windows 10 and Windows 7 there are hundreds of thousands of tutorials on that describe that process in great detail.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this, you'll need the install media for Windows 7 and a license key for Windows 7. If they're not available around you anymore, there are copies floating around ebay for relatively cheap.

Boot from the install media and select Custom Install. This should wipe the disk and install Windows 7.

WARNING: THIS WILL DELETE ALL CURRENT DATA FROM THE DRIVE

It may be possible to install without a full wipe, but not recommended.